# c++ std::list::push_back without copying existing instance

Tags: c++

I want to append an element to a list without copying any already existing variable.

```
int some_big_int = 123456789;
struct heavy_struct {
  std::vector<double> vec(some_big_number, 0);
};

std::list<heavy_struct> my_list;
heavy_struc new_item;
my_list.push_back(new_item);
```

If I understand correctly this is what happens:

- `heavy_struct` instance is created called new_item
- `my_list` creates a new `heavy_struct` instance in which `new_item` is copied

Is it possible to just append a new `heavy_struct`, without copying already existing structure?
This copying process is heavy and useless in this case.

Comment: in c++11 there's emplace_back

Comment: `new_item` is not "created"   since it  is a local stack variable. To create one you'd have to `heavy_struct  *new_item = new heavy_struct;` but don't forget to `delete` if afterwards.

Comment: You could also define a move constructor for `heavy_struct` and move it in with `my_list.push_back(std::move(new_item))`,

Comment: @Cameron that in case you want to do something with `new_item` before pushing it, otherwise I'd just use `emplace_back`

Comment: @Cameron In this case the compiler [should](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) create a functioning move constructor for you.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, but some of us are still on VS2013 (which has a lot of non-compliant behaviour when it comes to move constructors) :-) Anyway, I though it couldn't hurt to be aware of more possible implementations. Obviously, `emplace_back` is the way to go here, since that's what it's for.

Comment: @Cameron Tell me about it! That was why I used the word "should" :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
my_list.emplace_back();
```

Will pass its arguments (none in this case) to the `heavy_struct` object being constructed in-place in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list of pointers to your heavy struct, thus changing the heavy deep copy to a pointer asignment

```
std::list<heavy_struct*> my_list;
```

If you don't want to handle memory management either, go with shared pointers instead of raw ones.